# how to avoid __attribute__((weak)) multiple definition error on variables? [cl2.hpp]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, opencl

I'm including the [cl2.hpp](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/cl2_8hpp_source.html) header in multiple files inside my project and that triggered a multiple definition error and I don't know how to solve it.

Mainly, because I don't know in what occasions the `__attribute__((weak))` is needed or what is the way to use it. Can anybody help me with it??

Also I don't know if is a good idea to remove the lines that use `__attribute__((weak))` or Should I use another modifier?

In example:

```
# define CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ __attribute__((weak))

class Device : public detail::Wrapper<cl_device_id>
{
private:
    static std::once_flag default_initialized_;
    static Device default_;
    static cl_int default_error_;
    //More code
}

CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ std::once_flag Device::default_initialized_;
CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ Device Device::default_;
CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ cl_int Device::default_error_ = CL_SUCCESS;

class Platform : public detail::Wrapper<cl_platform_id>
{
private:
    static std::once_flag default_initialized_;
    static Platform default_;
    static cl_int default_error_;
    //More code
}

CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ std::once_flag Platform::default_initialized_;
CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ Platform Platform::default_;
CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ cl_int Platform::default_error_ = CL_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Normaly when you define a variable in multiple source files, the linker send you a "multiple definition" error. But if all those variables are declared with the weak attribute, the linker should not complain and only keep one definition. So you should not get that error if CL_HPP_DEFINE_STATIC_MEMBER_ is __attribute__((weak)) in all the source file. You should check that this is actually the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++17 you can declare those fields as inline:

```
class Device : public detail::Wrapper<cl_device_id>
{
private:
    static inline std::once_flag default_initialized_;
    static inline Device default_;
    static inline cl_int default_error_;
    //More code
}
```

Prior to C++17 you can use a trick with a template:

```
template<typename x_Dummy>
class t_StaticFieldsHolder
{
    friend class Device;
    static std::once_flag default_initialized_;
    static Device default_;
    static cl_int default_error_;
};

template<typename x_Dummy> 
std::once_flag t_StaticFieldsHolder<x_Dummy>::default_initialized_;

template<typename x_Dummy> 
Device t_StaticFieldsHolder<x_Dummy>::default_;

template<typename x_Dummy> 
cl_int t_StaticFieldsHolder<x_Dummy>::default_error_;
```